# In first post review page mouse hover effect does not work for some users?

Tags: support

I have seen the tool tip like popup for most of the users when mouse over the users but i am able to see this effect of some user.

Is it a bug or need some settings?

[image]

Do not show effect on :-

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is by design, as described on [How does the User Card popup work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104810/how-does-the-user-card-popup-work) You can see it if the following conditions happen:

- The user reputation is at least 1000
- The *About Me* text is long enough
- The *About Me* text doesn't contain `<!-- summary: &nbsp; -->`
- The page you are seeing is a question and answer detail page, a page with a list of questions, or the users list page
- The question or the answer is not wiki

In any case, when the user popup is available, the user icon will be rendered with a border.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you so much i will check the post.